# Error : The tuning parameter grid should have columns mtry, SVM Regression

Tags: r, regression, svm, r-caret

I'm trying to tune an SVM regression model using the caret package. Below the code:

```
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5)
tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry=c(6:12), .ntree=c(500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000))
set.seed(2)
custom <- train(CRTOT_03~., data=train, method="rf", metric="rmse", tuneGrid=tunegrid, trControl=control)
summary(custom)
plot(custom)
```

and Im getting the error

```
Error : The tuning parameter grid should have columns mtry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Random Forests, not Support Vector machines. You are getting an error, because you can set `.mtry` only in the tuning grid for Random Forests in `caret` The `ntree` parameter is set by passing `ntree` to `train`, e.g.

```
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5)
tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = 6:12)
set.seed(2)
custom <- train(CRTOT_03~., 
          data=train, method="rf", 
          metric="rmse", 
          tuneGrid=tunegrid, 
          ntree = 1000,
          trControl=control)
```

`ntree` is passed directly to `randomForest`